# Any WYSIWYG editors that are free and look modern like Froala?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, themes

There are several WYSIWYG editors out there, such as TinyMCE, CKEditor, etc. However, IMHO these editors don't have a nice and modern appearance like Froala. Problem is that Froala costs, and it sucks because this is just an internal app that I plan on using long-term without anyone else even looking at it.

TinyMCE and CKEditor also seem to have some pretty terrible themes. I'm ultimately wanting to get something inside of my ruby on rails application.

Does anyone know of any modern looking WYSIWYG editors that actually look like they were developed in the last 10 years? I have a beautiful theme for my rails app and I just don't want to kill it with some old looking theme.

Not looking to get flamed and yes I've googled, but I came here because I really can't find what I'm looking for and hoping someone else can shed some light.

Comment: Quill.js is nice and lots of other open-source editors are now available. In all cases avoid Froala. Their legal team is the worst, will force you to buy their enterprise license for even a simple informational website. Do not even test their product on the live domain or even sub-domain without purchasing a license for any reason even if you plan to purchase a license later. They'll contact you to charge you the legal penalty and threaten you to file a case against you and force you to purchase an enterprise license even if it's not applicable to you, a friend's experience has been such.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't see a whole lot of difference between Freola and TinyMCE, or the HTML editor this website uses.

Can you list specific features you're looking for that the items in the list don't do?  I know you mentioned theming, but there are literally hundreds of themes for TinyMCE and you can roll your own without much effort at all.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Just going to be using very basic features such as tyling (bold, italiac, underline), paragraph (ol, il), links, and that's probably about it. For some reason the way TinyMCE looks really bothers me. The buttons don't have a modern styling, etc.  I can't really find any themes for it either -- only found one actually. If you don't mind, could you point me to where these themes are?

Comment: You shouldn't be bothered by the look of it - most of the top end WYSIWYG can be styled / have themes you can use.

Answer (score 0):

The best WYSIWYG I've come across is [`Redactor`](https://imperavi.com/redactor/). It costs $500 for a developer license:

[image]

There is a gem called [`redactor-rails`](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails) which provides it **for free** (I don't know how).

It is the most efficient & good-looking I've come across.

---

If you want functionality with the likes of [`Paperclip`](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#how-to-generate-models-to-store-uploaded-files) etc, we've used [`CKEditor`](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) extensively. Yes, it looks crappy but I believe there are ways to style it:

[image]

I can give you the code we use if you want to try it. Once you get rid of 99% of the non-essential elements, it starts to look good.

Comment: It's been more than 4 years, so this answer is no more appropriate. Both TinyMCE and CKEditor looks modern, and a lot of other options are out there now.